# Execution time rBayesianOptimization

Tags: r, optimization, bayesian, hyperparameters

Is there an option to set the rBayesianOptimization runtime.

It would be very useful to be able to stop it when there is no convergence.

Thank you.

[RBayesianOptimization Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rBayesianOptimization/rBayesianOptimization.pdf)

Comment: You can specify the number of iterations.

Comment: Convergence is difficult to determine for Bayesian optimization. You would have to know some characteristics of your objective function to ensure that the optimization is not just currently on a plateau.